# Como quebrar linha após botão no Angular com Materialize?

Tags: html, css, angular, materialize

Fazendo uma pequena página utilizando Angular, me deparei com um problema de sobreposição de dois botões. Quando estão em telas de mais de 420 px de largura (celular em posição horizontal, por exemplo), não se torna um problema, e os botões se posicionam da forma mostrada abaixo:

[image: Botões em exibição normal (telas de mais de 420 pixels de largura)]

Mas, quando se está com um dispositivo de menos de 420 px de tamanho horizontal (BlackBerry Z30, por exemplo), a página não quebra a linha, mas sobrepõe os botões, como na imagem a seguir:

[image: Botões com aparência sobreposta (telas de menos de 420 pixels de largura]

O que eu queria é que, quando se usasse um dispositivo com essa configuração, se quebrasse a linha, ficando os dois botões um abaixo do outro. Como é possível ver no HTML abaixo, já tive que usar um `span` de uma  linha inteira para separar os botões dos outros campos (para eles não se sobreporem aos campos).

Estrutura da página:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- campos do formulário -->

      <span class="col s12"></span>

      <div class="input-field col s4">

        <a class="btn-large red">cancelar</a>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <button class="btn-large blue" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Mantive o CSS do componente da página vazio.

Estou usando Angular 8 e Materialize CSS.

Edit: consegui evitar a sobreposição dos botões removendo eles dos containers, dessa forma:

```
<!-- original -->
<div class="input-field col s4">

  <a class="btn-large red">cancelar</a>
</div>
<div class="col s4">
    <button class="btn-large blue" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</div>
<!-- modificado -->
<a class="col s4 btn-large red">cancelar</a>
<button class="col s4 push-s5 btn-large blue" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
```

Mas eles ainda assim não quebram a linha ao ficarem próximos demais, e agora se distorcem até virarem um risco colorido no meio da tela.

Comment: Será que isso não é por causa da classe `input-field` na div? É só um chute mesmo....

Comment: Pior que não, removi a classe e o problema persistiu...

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar de vez o problema, criei no CSS do componente uma classe chamada `bloco`:

```
.bloco{
  display: block;
  min-width: 10em;
}
```

E adicionei a classe a ambos os botões (criando um span para separá-los):

```
<a class="col s4 btn-large red bloco" [routerLink]="['/bank-accounts']">cancelar</a>
<span class="col s1"></span>
<button class="col s4 push-s5 btn-large blue bloco" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
```

Como a classe, basicamente, cria um tamanho mínimo para o componente, isso fez com que os objetos não se sobrepusessem ao chegarem próximos demais um do outro, gerando o resultado a seguir:

[image: resultado final]